# GqlQuery from GoogleAppEngine returns empty list

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, gql, gqlquery

Here is my query:

```
currentID = 7
deck = range(0,3)
similarIDs = db.GqlQuery('SELECT * FROM itemSet WHERE jokeID=:1 AND position IN :2', currentID, deck[:3]).fetch(100)
```

Here is my model:

```
class itemSet(db.Model):
jokeID = db.IntegerProperty()
jokeID2 = db.IntegerProperty()
position = db.IntegerProperty()
```

When I execute the query in the GoogleAppEngine Data Viewer, I get the results:
[image]

What am I missing?

Comment: When I execute the code above in similarIDs I get list with 3 empty elements, `[,,]` and I need to get the same result as in the GAE Data Viewer..

Comment: Show us the code that processes the result of the query. I have a very similar query one of my apps, and it works as expected.

Comment: @Dave when I try to show the entity itself in the webpage I get `<google.appengine.ext.db.GqlQuery object at 0x7378079cb5d55750>`, and when I try to access a property I get the following
 `AttributeError: 'GqlQuery' object has no attribute 'jokeID'`.. I feel like I'm misuising GqlQuery.

Comment: Sounds like you are trying to work with the query object itself rather than looping through the resulting entities.

Comment: Please include the code that's actually causing the problem in your question!

Comment: The error was in the python code inside my html file, where I was showing the results, a typo..

Answer (score 1):

The following code with your GqlQuery statements works for me.

```
    item = itemSet()
    item.jokeID = 7
    item.jokeID2 = 1
    item.position = 0
    item.put()
    item = itemSet()
    item.jokeID = 7
    item.jokeID2 = 2
    item.position = 1
    item.put()

    currentID = 7
    deck = range(0,3)
    similarIDs = db.GqlQuery('SELECT * FROM itemSet \
                             WHERE jokeID=:1 AND position IN :2'
                             , currentID, deck[:3]).fetch(100)
    for item in similarIDs:
        logging.info("%s : %s" % (item.jokeID, item.position))
```

It returns:

```
INFO     2011-09-19 18:46:28,299 main.py:47] 7 : 0
INFO     2011-09-19 18:46:28,299 main.py:47] 7 : 1
```

Comment: Indeed..
My mistake was in the python code inside my html file.